# Is it possible to repeat a loop every 10 minutes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have this loop ( a song) executed and then wait for 10 Minutes,before it will repeat itself.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

var audio =    document.createElement("");

audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
audio.play();

};
```

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: have you considered using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Wrap that in a function, then call setInterval() on it. Pass the function as the first parameter, and the second parameter is the time in milliseconds to repeat the calling of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It easily can be done like this:

```
function play () {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

  var audio =    document.createElement("audio");

  audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
  audio.play();

  };
}



setInterval(play, 600000);  
//the function name.  do not put () after it as you aren't executing it.  
//600000 is the number of milliseconds in 10 minutes.

play(); //this will execute it immediately the first time if you want.
```

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

      var audio = document.createElement("audio");

      audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
      audio.play();
    } 
}, 600 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** or **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)**, but you cannot count on it being precisely 10 minutes because the function will get queued in the event loop and will only fire after its timeout time has been reached and the JavaScript runtime is idle.

`setTimeout()` takes a callback function as its first argument and a number (in milliseconds) to wait as its second. Think of the number as the "minimal amount of time to wait" until the timeout function is invoked.

```
function go(){
  // Clear the previous timer
  timer = null;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {     
    var audio =    document.createElement("audio");  
    audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
    audio.play();
  }

  // Re-run the timer
  timer = setTimeout(go, 600000);
}

var timer = setTimeout(go, 600000);
```

Or, with `setInterval()`:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {     
    var audio =    document.createElement("audio");  
    audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
    audio.play();
  } 
}, 600000);
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Two correct answers with documentation?!

Comment: Both answers throw an error because of the missing element name in document.createElement(). I've edited those in and you rolled back the edit.

Comment: Corrected. But, that was the OPs code and not really pertinent to the answer.

Comment: Reverted the vote - _But, that was the OPs code_ your answer should fix that, _not really pertinent to the answer._ an answer should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @baao I rolled back your edit because I was in the process of editing my answer while you made your edit. And, I do believe that my answer was still good without that edit, because neither the problem with that line or its correction had any direct relevance to the question or the correct answer to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to use setInterval() or setTimeout

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

The first one, executes every X time, the second one executes after X time has passed, wich one to use depends on how infinite is your loop or if you want to exit it sometime, for wich you can evaluate in setTimeout before execution or use clearInterval() for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that calls itself after a timeout and call it once

```
function createAudioElement() {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

        var audio = document.createElement("audio");  
        audio.src = "my_sound.mp3";
        audio.play();
  };

  setTimeout(createAudioElement, 600000);
}

createAudioElement();
```

Make sure to specify what element to create in `document.createElement()`- in this case `audio`, otherwise it will throw an error.